# Dynamically count the number of columns in a SAS table

Tags: sas

I need to create a footer record that displays semicolons that are equal to number of columns in the table. The table  have 47 columns but this may change so I need to dynamically count the columns without using dictionary tables. The footer record will be exported to a csv file and it's delimiter is a semicolon.

I tried this code below, it works but when exporting the data to a csv file, the semicolons are enclosed with double quotation marks even if I used dequote function. Any idea to remove them? Thanks in advance.

```
proc contents data=input out=output noprint; run;
proc sort data=output; by varnum; run; 
  data _null_; 
    set output;
    call symputx("maximum",varnum);
  run;
  data semis; 
    length ffsemis $47; 
    ffsemis = repeat(';',&maximum*1);
*   call symputx("semis",ffsemis); 
  run;
  data _null_;
    file "E:\semis.csv" delimiter=';' dsd dropover;
    set work.semis;
    if _n_=1 then do;
    put ffsemis;
  end;
  run;
```

Comment: At the moment your logic seems to be based on the number of variables in the dataset, not the number of rows. Are you sure you want semicolons = rows?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I meant was to count the columns or variables in a dataset. Yes, that's the requirement of the change request.

Comment: The requirement for the change request is to number of semicolons equal to the number of columns. 47 columns = ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

Comment: Is the data step above how you write to csv or you append a footer record to the table before export?

Comment: The code above is how I write to CSV, though it's just a snippet of it.

Comment: The footer record dataset should not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of to determine the number of variables in a SAS dataset is with proc contents.

Create a new dataset with the contents of the data and run a null data step to save the maximum variable number to a macro variable. Be aware that macro variables are saved as character values so you must make sure it is converted back to numeric by performing a numeric operation on the value in order to use your new macro variable as a number in your code.

```
proc contents data=input out=output; run;

proc sort data=output; by varnum; run;

data _null_; 
    set output;
    call symputx("maximum",varnum);
run;

data semis; 
    length ffsemis $27; 
    ffsemis = repeat(%str(;),&maximum*1);
    call symputx("semis",ffsemis); 
run;

%put SEMIS = "&semis.";

proc export data=semis file="C:\semis.csv";
run;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank u for your input. I tried your code and it worked to get the max number of columns. But when I used the REPEAT function to have an equal number of semicolons it failed since REPEAT function and semicolon are character. Any suggestion for this scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added the below code and it seems to work properly. A single variable is created with many semicolons.
data semis;
ffsemis = repeat(';',&maximum*1);
run;

Comment: Thanks JJFord3, I tried your code to export data to a csv file and the semicolons are still enclosed with double quotations.

Comment: I tweaked my previous post and this definitely works to put only the semi-colons to the csv file.

Comment: I changed my code to add your code and to how I am trying to export to a csv file. The exported file is still enclosed with double quotations.

Comment: Changed ';' to %str(;)... no more quotes. Untested... should work theoretically.